# Virtual Overridden method differing only in return type gives compilation error

Tags: c++, inheritance

A virtual function if not overridden properly, should compile fine.(Proper function may not be called).
Program 1 runs fine -- Overridden function differs on parameter and return types.
Program 2 gives error -- Overridden function differs only on return types.

Why is Program 2 giving error and Program 1 runs fine ?

Program 1:

```
    class Base {
    public:
    virtual int fun(int i)
    {
        cout << "Base::fun(int i) called";
    }
    };
    class Derived : public Base
    {
    public:
    virtual double fun()
    {
        cout << "Derived::fun() called";
    }
    };
   // Driver Code 
    Derived d;
    Base& b = d;
    b.fun(5);
```

`Program 2:`

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual int fun(int i)
    {
      cout << "Base::fun(int i) called";
    }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual double fun(int i)
    {
          cout << "Derived::fun() called";
    }
};
```

`

Comment: In example 1, `Derived::fun()` isn't overriding `Base::fun(int)`, it's hiding it. (You could see this if you tried calling `d.fun(5);` instead of `b.fun(5);`. Regardless, what is your actual question?

Comment: @NathanPierson: why is program 2 giving error? When will it hide and when will it override ?

Comment: It hides when it has a different signature. It overrides when it has the same signature (possibly differing by having a covariant return type, like returning a `Derived*` instead of a `Base*`). Remember also that the point of virtual functions is that a pointer to base that's pointing to an object of the derived type will call the function of the derived class. So what should happen if `Base::func()` returned an `int` but `Derived::func()`, ostensibly overriding it, returned `void` and you called `int x = b.func()`?

Comment: @NathanPierson: We are not able to override in both the cases, but one Program runs fine and other errors out. Why ?

Comment: Program 2's Derived class violated the contract of the Base class.  (And both programs have **undefined behavior** because they don't return what they promised to return.)

Comment: @AnirbanSaha In the first case, the compiler is still able to tell which function to call when. In the second case, the arguments are the same, meaning that `Derived::fun` really should override `Base::fun`, except it has the wrong return type. This is more obvious if `Derived::fun` had a totally incompatible return type like `void` or `std::string`, but for consistency the standard doesn't allow you to override with a different return type except in very constrained circumstances, and `double` vs `int` isn't one of them.